# Display custom checkout address field 2 label in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I found a way to change the placeholder but not the label of the checkout input fields in woocommerce.

I would like to change the label for the `adress_field_2`.

Here is my attempt that did not change anything. I tried [label] and [label_class] but that did not work...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'new_checkout_field_label', 10, 1 );
function new_checkout_field_label( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = __( '', 'woocommerce' );
    $address_fields['address_2']['label'] = __( 'Apt, Unit, Etc (optional)', 'woocommerce' );
    return $address_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Your code works and the correct related html is there. But it's hidden from the tag class `screen-reader-text` by a CSS rule.

To make the `<label>` visible, you need to remove the class from the `<label>` tag adding this line:

```
$address_fields['address_2']['label_class'] = array(); // No label class
```

So in your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_default_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
function custom_override_default_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = __( '', 'woocommerce' );
    $address_fields['address_2']['label'] = __( 'Apt, Unit, Etc (optional)', 'woocommerce' );
    $address_fields['address_2']['label_class'] = array(); // No label class

    return $address_fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]